# Is it possible to mark and save a particular bash script line number and restart the script at that saved position?

Tags: shell, numbers, line

I need to know if it is possible to mark a bash script line number and then restart that script at the saved line number.

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do #I'm reading from a big wordlist
command1 using $line
command2 using $line
done
```

Specifically, is there a way to write the current $line number of the script automatically into a separate text file in order for the script to start from the line number specified, so that I won't have to start everything from scratch in case I have to stop the script?

Does it make sense?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Does this file just grow like a log file? Is it an option to use tail instead?

Comment: The wordlist I'm reading from does not grow. But it's quite big (20MB).

Comment: 20 MB is no critical size. How long does this take?

Comment: About 6hours to process 10,000 words. That's less than 1% of the total wordlist. I'm guessing I will spend weeks going through the entire list, but that's fine. I just need a way to resume the script so that I don't start from scratch

Comment: What the hell are you doing with these words?

Comment: I'm querying a server and processing the results. It can't be sped up, I'm afraid. But once again, that's fine. All I need is a way to resume  the script when I stop it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help:

```
#!/bin/bash

TMP_FILE="/tmp/currentLineNumber"                         # a constant

current_line_count=0                                      # track the current line number

processed_lines_count=0

# Verify if we have already processed some stuff.
if [ -r "${TMP_FILE}" ]; then
  processed_lines_count=$(cat ${TMP_FILE})
fi

while read -r line; do                                    # I 'm reading from a big wordlist

    # Skip processing till we reach the line that needs to be processed.

    if [ $current_line_count -le $processed_line_count ]; then

      # do nothing as this line has already been processed
      current_line_count=$((current_line_count+1))        # increment the counter
      continue

    fi

    current_line_count=$((current_line_count+1))
    echo $current_line_count > ${TMP_FILE}                # cache the line number

    # perform your operations
    command1 using $line
    command2 using $line

done
```

Comment: It's working great. I really feel that I've been spoonfed. Thank you again

Comment: Thank you for sharing the update bobylapointe. Glad to know that the solution served the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    I=`cat lastline`;
    A=0;

    while read -r line; do
           if [$A>=$I]; then
               command1 using $line
               command2 using $line
               (( I++ ))
               echo "$I" > "lastline";
           fi;
           (( A++ ))
    done
```

Remember you will have to delete lastline if you want to restart. :-)

Comment: I'm going to give it a try, thank you very much for taking the time to understand my problem and providing me with a solution Oliver.

Answer (score 1):

The bash-only solutions are nice, but you may get better performance by using other tools to streamline your restart.  Like the script in your question, the following takes the wordlist on stdin.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Get the current position, or 0 if we haven't run before
if [ -f /tmp/processed ]; then
  read processed < /tmp/processed
else
  processed=0
fi

# Skip up to the current position
awk -v processed="$processed" 'NR > processed' | while read -r line; do

  # Run your commands
  command1 using $line
  command2 using $line

  # Record our new position
  processed=$((processed + 1))
  echo $processed > /tmp/processed

done
```

Oh, and the way I wrote this, it's Bourne shell compatible, so it doesn't require bash.